# The Icon App dosen't appear in my activities

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

when I update my SDK the icon app doesn't appear in the activities I tried all the solution on the internet but nothing happened .. I tried also to put **" android:icon"** in each activities nothing change also made a custom actionbar also nothing change .. please any help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package=""
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
"
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Option"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_option" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CustomList"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_custom_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Social"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_social" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActionBar"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_action_bar" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please show us ur custom theme

Comment: <resources>
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
            
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    

        
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: even if I create a new project as a hello word the same problem the icon app dosen't appear

Comment: i know that just try the following <item name="icon">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>. If it does'nt works set from Java code.OKK Let me know if it works

Comment: the same .. nothing change

how can I set it from java code?

Comment: Is your icon called ic_launcher and is it in all your drawable folders with appropriate sizes?

Comment: yes every thing was good before updated .. now even if I create anew project as hello world the icon app dosen't appear in the activities